# reference member functions calling

Tags: c++, reference

I have written the following member function of a class Point

```
    double  &Function(){
     double d=33.66;
     double *p=new double;
     p=&d;
     return *p;
    }
```

which is being called in the main () using Point object "pt" as, pt.Function(). This works, although I don't quite understand why? Can it be improved? I know this is not the best way to get the value of "d" but I use it to learn how to pass values using reference. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your function is 4 lines long, and has 2 major issues. Impressive.

Comment: You don't *pass* by reference. *Passing* is what happens to *arguments* of functions when being called. You *return* a reference. And you return a reference to a variable that will go out of scope once the function returns, and therefore will cease to exist, leaving you with a reference to something that doesn't exist. Perhaps you should take a couple of steps back, [get a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and start over.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I for sure need to learn c++.

Answer (score 0):

```
 p=&d;
```

Here, It's just creating a **[memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)**. You will never get to use that allocated memory in this instance of the program.

Comment: It's also creating a dangling reference

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return the value of a POD (Plain Old Data) local variable, which is d in your case by reference. You can simply return it by value.

A possible scenario where you will need to return something by reference is when the value is a member of your class, and you need to modify it from somewhere else.

Example:

```
// Declaration
class Point {
private:
    double _d = 33.66;
public:
    double& getD() { return _d; }
}

// Usage
Point p;
p.getD() = 66.33;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I am new to c++. By the way, can I not return a non-member variable "d" using function getD()?

Comment: If you return a reference to a local variable, that reference would become invalid as soon as the local variable's lifetime ends, which is after the function returns. Trying to access that reference would cause undefined behavior.